# API application needs session?

Tags: javascript, express

i'm creating an API and i would like to know if i need use express-session or something related to deal with sessions.

```
app.use(expressSession({
 secret: 'Something'
});
```

Currently i'm blocking CORS. This is not enough to block people that want take my data??

Thanks.

Comment: I see you are also posting a secret key to your server for validation? CORS alone is not enough, the data is still available for grasp if they ignore CORS rules.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be using sessions for an api. Take a look at using json web tokens for [auth](https://auth0.com/blog/2014/12/02/using-json-web-tokens-as-api-keys/)